# Update MYSQL with IF statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my MYSQL table, but with a condition.

I have a status field and a time field. If status=day, don't update time field with the current time. if status=night, update time field with current time.

Right now, I am doing a SELECT statement, then an if statement on the returned value in PHP and then performing the UPDATE and changing all fields except the time unless status=night. Is it possible to do this all in one command?

---

Edit:

Sorry, just to clarify:

A WHERE command will only update the row if status=night. I always want all the fields within the row to be updated, but only update the time field if status=night. If status=day, update the entire row except for the time field.

---

Code:

```
if($status=="night") {
    $query = "UPDATE post SET name="$name", comment="$comment", status="$status", time="{now()}" WHERE id='$id'";
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE post SET name="$name", comment="$comment", status="$status" WHERE id='$id'"
}
```

Comment: show us you actual code then we can make suggestions.

Comment: A WHERE clause would be like UPDATE table SET time=time() WHERE status='status'. I want it to update the row no matter what the status is, but only change the time field if status=night.

Comment: It would be easy to assist, if you provide those two `MySQL` query you are using.

Comment: Quickly typed out the code and through it into original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = val1, time=IF(status="night",NOW(),time), field3= val3;
```

Comment: This will only update the row when status=night. I need it to update all the fields within the row no matter the status except for 'time' unless status=night.

Comment: That is great, but it's not giving me the correct result. It will update time if the new status=night. I need it to update time if the status before the update=night. If the old status was day and I set it to night, it will still update the time.

Comment: Oh my bad. In this case, I think the answer is no, there's no better way than the code you gave. I mean, you can always set a variable in sql and do the same, but it's just easier the way you did it already.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `time` = NOW() WHERE `status` = `night`
```